# Dúvida no C# com html

Tags: c#, html, imagem

Tenho uma aplicação que carrega uma imagem que está dentro do projeto.
Quando passo o diretório manualmente (ex.: `src="~/Imagens/logoACESSO.png"`) ele carrega a imagem normalmente, mas quando eu pego o mesmo caminho por uma variável do C# ele não carrega a imagem (ex.: `src="@chegadas.Ds_Caminho_Logo"`).

O valor da variável está exatamente igual ao caminho: ~/Imagens/logoACESSO.png.

Código HTML

```
<div>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-active" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
    <thead style="background-color:black; color: white; font-size: 22px;">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 150px;">EMPRESA</th>
            <th style="width: 260px;">ORIGEM</th>
            <th style="width: 300px;">DESTINO</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 120px;">CHEGADA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">PARTIDA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">BOX</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">OBSERVAÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 18px;">
        @foreach (var chegadas in Model)
                {
                    string caminhoImagem = chegadas.Ds_Caminho_Logo;

                    if (@chegadas.Ds_Cidade_Origem == "CHEGADAS DO DIA")
                    {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @chegadas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @chegadas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @chegadas.Hr_Chegada_Local
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    @*<td style="text-align: left;">@chegadas.Ds_Empresa</td>*@
                    @if (chegadas.Ds_Caminho_Logo == null)
                    {
                        <td style="text-align: left;">@chegadas.Ds_Empresa</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td style="text-align: left;"><img height="35" src="@new HtmlString(chegadas.Ds_Caminho_Logo)" /></td>

                        @*<td style="text-align: left;"><img height="35" src="~/Imagens/logoACESSO.png" /></td>*@
                    }
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">@chegadas.Ds_Cidade_Origem</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">@chegadas.Ds_Cidade_Destino</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">@chegadas.Hr_Chegada_Local</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><!-- CHEGADAS NÃO MOSTRA HORA DE PARTIDA --> @*@chegadas.Hr_Saida_Local*@</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">@chegadas.Ds_Plataforma</td>
                    <td style="color: red;"><marquee>@chegadas.Ds_Observacao</marquee></td>
                    @*<td><div class="marquee"><span>@chegadas.Ds_Observacao</span></div></td>*@
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Código Controller

```
public class PainelPartidasEChegadasController : Controller
{

    // GET: PainelPartida
    public ActionResult PainelPartidas()
    {
        PainelPartidaDAO dao = new PainelPartidaDAO();
        IList<PainelPartida> partidas = dao.Partidas();
        ViewBag.Title = "Partidas";

        return View(partidas);
    }

    public ActionResult PainelChegadas()
    {
        PainelChegadaDAO dao = new PainelChegadaDAO();
        IList<PainelChegada> chegadas = dao.Chegadas();
        ViewBag.Title = "Chegadas";

        return View(chegadas);
    }
}
```

Código DAO

```
public IList<PainelChegada> Chegadas()
    {
        /*
         * consulta feita passando a query pelo C#
         * 
         * var lista = new List<PainelChegada>();
         * var select = conexao.CreateCommand();
         * select.CommandText = "select e.Ds_Empresa, l.Cd_Cod_Linha, l.Ds_Cidade_Origem, l.Ds_Cidade_Destino, l.Hr_Chegada_Local, l.Hr_Saida_Local, p.Ds_Observacao, l.Hr_Chegada_Destino from Cd_Linha l, Cd_Partidas p, Cd_Empresa e, cd_parametro r where l.Cd_Cod_Linha = p.Cd_Cod_Linha and e.Cd_Empresa = l.Cd_Empresa and l.Ds_Cidade_Origem <> r.ds_cidade_origem order by l.Hr_Chegada_Local asc";
        */

        //Consulta feita passando procedures do SQL
        var lista = new List<PainelChegada>();

        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SP_Painel_Partida_Chegada", conexao);

        select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Exec", "SEL");
        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("Procedimento", 2);

        int contador = 0;
        var resultado = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (resultado.Read())
        {
            PainelChegada pc = new PainelChegada();

            if (Convert.ToString(resultado["PrevSaida"]) == "----------")
            {
                string proximaData = Convert.ToString(resultado["EfetivaChegada"]);
                string diaDaSemana = Convert.ToString(resultado["Observacao"]);

                pc.Ds_Empresa = "";
                pc.Cd_Cod_Linha = "";
                pc.Ds_Cidade_Origem = "CHEGADAS DO DIA";
                pc.Ds_Cidade_Destino = proximaData;
                pc.Hr_Chegada_Local = diaDaSemana;
                pc.Hr_Saida_Local = "";
                pc.Ds_Observacao = "";

                lista.Add(pc);
                contador++;
            }
            else if (contador < 13)
            {

                pc.Ds_Empresa = Convert.ToString(resultado["Empresa"]);
                pc.Ds_Caminho_Logo = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_Caminho_Logo"]);
                pc.Cd_Cod_Linha = Convert.ToString(resultado["Linha"]);
                pc.Ds_Cidade_Origem = Convert.ToString(resultado["CidadeOrigem"]);
                pc.Ds_Cidade_Destino = Convert.ToString(resultado["CidadeDestino"]);
                pc.Hr_Chegada_Local = Convert.ToString(resultado["PrevChegada"]);
                pc.Hr_Saida_Local = Convert.ToString(resultado["PrevSaida"]);
                pc.Ds_Observacao = Convert.ToString(resultado["Observacao"]);
                pc.Ds_Plataforma = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_Plataforma"]);

                lista.Add(pc);
                contador++;

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        resultado.Close();

        return lista;
    }
```

Comment: `~/Imagens/logoACESSO.png` e `/Imagens/logoACESSO.png` são caminhos diferentes. Tem certeza que está correto o `path` vindo da variável?

Comment: Já editei Marcelo, os caminhos são exatamente iguais. Eu copiei do banco de dados para os dois exemplos.

Comment: Tente utilizar src="@new HtmlString(chegadas.Ds_Caminho_Logo)"

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates dá erro quando vou compilar. Erro CS1031: Type expected. Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o código fonte apropriadamente.

Comment: Edita tua questão e adiciona o código que estás utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução! Vou colocar como resposta caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema futuramente.

A aplicação estava salvando o caminho da imagem da forma que o Visual Studio auto-completa o mapeamento de seus diretórios, ou seja ele coloca o "~" antes do mapeamento do diretório (Ex.: `~/Imagens/logoACESSO.png`). Quando escrevemos direto no Visual Studio dessa forma ele reconhece como caracter válido, mas quando vem do banco o Visual Studio não reconhece o caracter.

Acredito que por algum motivo o SQL deve usar bytes diferentes que o Visual Studio para representar o "~".

Mas a solução é essa: ao gravar no banco o caminho da imagem, tem que retirar o "~".

Comment: você não está 100% certo em sua conclusão, o ~/ indica que o caminho será referente à raiz da aplicação e isso será interpretado resultando no valor final... faça o teste em uma página puro html.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema parecido com o seu, e a solução que achei foi armazenar a imagem em binario no banco de dados, e assim carregar ela com o codigo abaixo.

Abaixo a view que carrega os dados.

```
@model BDM.Models.MdImagemProd
@{
    Layout = null;
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImagemData);
    var imgscr = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
}
<img src='@imgscr' style="height:100px; width:100px" />
```